# Convert types Metaprogramming

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

i´m newbie, i don´t know meta-programming, i´m trying convert a list like this

`Typelist<long, float, char>` in `Typelist<std::array<long, 10>, std::array<float, 10>, std::array<char, 10>>`

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Ts>
struct Typelist {};

template <typename List>
struct front{};

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct front<Typelist<Head, Tail...>>
{
    using type = Typelist<std::array<Head, 10>, front<Typelist<Tail...>>>;
};

void seetype(auto) {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}

int main()
{
    using list_of_types = Typelist<long, float, char>;
    using arrays_of_types = front<list_of_types>::type;
    seetype(arrays_of_types{});
    return 0;
}
```

result is this

```
void seetype(auto) [auto:1 = Typelist<std::array<long, 10>, front<Typelist<float, char>>>]
```

only first type is ok, rest bad......what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your code:

```
front<Typelist<Tail...>>
```

is not the type modified, you would need

```
typename front<Typelist<Tail...>>::type
```

(which is a `Typelist`)
Then base case of the recursion is not handled:

```
template<typename Head>
struct front<Typelist<Head>>
{
    using type = Typelist<std::array<Head, 10>>;
};
```

With that, the resulting typelist is not concatenated correctly [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6af6a69E8), so:

```
template<typename List1, typename List2>
struct concat {};

template<typename... Ts, typename...Us>
struct concat<Typelist<Ts...>, Typelist<Us...>> {
    using type = Typelist<Ts..., Us...>;
};
```

and

```
template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct front<Typelist<Head, Tail...>>
{
    using type = typename concat<Typelist<std::array<Head, 10>>,
                                 typename front<Typelist<Tail...>>::type>::type;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7v8EjTd79)

But you don't need the recursion at all:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct front<Typelist<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Typelist<std::array<Ts, 10>...>;
};
```

is enough:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f3535PP7M)

To be even more generic:

```
template <template <typename> class F, typename List>
struct Mapping{
};

template<template <typename> class F, typename... Ts>
struct Mapping<F, Typelist<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Typelist<typename F<Ts>::type...>;
};

template<typename T>
struct to_array_10
{
    using type = std::array<T, 10>;
};

using list_of_types = Typelist<long, float, char>;
using arrays_of_types = Mapping<to_array_10, list_of_types>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c7zGbfrnK)